# Wine equivalent for Linux packages on MacOS

Tags: macintosh, wine, deb

I'm not sure that this is the right place to ask this, but I was wondering if there was a way to run Linux files, and more specifically install .deb files, on MacOS. Sort of like the opposite of Wine? I've looked at fink, but it seems to lack the ability to do exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: running it inside a virtual machine is not an option?

Comment: I actually dual booted Ubuntu 16.04, but my graphics card (Intel HD 4000) wouldn't work with opengl 4.1 on Mesa, and the whole reason I'm doing this is to get that working for a game that only runs on Linux and windows but not Mac (saints row 3)

Comment: I think your best bet would be running the Windows binary with Wine. I can expect the performance would be quite abysmal even if you were to run it natively though, to be honest.

Comment: @undercat directx 9 works but fails when I start a new game, and 10 and 11 won't even start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazingly enough [Karton](https://karton.github.io/) was released today and might satisfy your requirements. It uses containers to provide runtime Linux environments on Linux and macOS. You can specify what Linux distribution to use, what packages to install, what directories to share, and then run Linux commands pretty much transparently.

Comment: Ok so I didn't end up using Karton, but it led me to docker so now I'm using docker with Ubuntu and tunneling x over ssh using xquartz. Thanks for your help